# Spring LDAP implementation failover capability

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ldap

I am using LDAP with spring mvc 3. I want to configure it in a way where if my primary LDAP URL fails to connect then it connects to secondary LDAP URL. Can it be managed in spring configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `urls` property (pass it an array of ldap server urls) instead of the `url` property on your `LDAPContextSource` bean in your spring config. This will allow it to fail over if it can't talk to the first server.

Comment: Does Spring support the `altServer` attribute from the root DSE?